# Docker Stack LTS will always re-download and re-create GHC from scratch

Tags: docker, haskell, haskell-stack, dockerhub, lts

With the following Dockerfile

```
FROM fpco/stack-build:lts-17.12 as dependencies

ENV STACK_ROOT /home/stackage/.stack

COPY ./stack.yaml ./package.yaml ./

RUN stack build --dependencies-only
```

Stack will *always* start by downloading and installing GHC from scratch before building.

```
> [dependencies 5/7] RUN stack build --dependencies-only                                                                     2.8s
 => => # Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.                                                                                               
 => => # This will not interfere with any system-level installation.                                                                                     
 => => # Preparing to download ghc-8.10.4 ...                                                                                                            
 => => # ghc-8.10.4: download has begun   
 => => # ...
```

I've tried different values for the `STACK_ROOT` environment variable (including none, leaving the default) but none of it worked.

Now, if I comment out the `RUN stack build` line and just pull the image, then run a shell into it, I can see that GHC and Stack are already pre-installed in `/home/stackage/.stack`, with the Linux binaries.

How comes Stack always chooses to download and install everything from scratch every time despite this? Is there a way to avoid it?

EDIT: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60749522) seemed to indicate that using `STACK_ROOT=/home/stackage/.stack` would work, but apparently it doesn't — maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: does the resolver for your project match lts-17.12?

Comment: yes it does — but note that even if I don't specify a `stack.yaml` (where the resolver is declared) it will still re-download GHC again, after having created a default stack.yaml.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me - I guess you could do a workaround by adding a layer after the download but yeah not nice

Comment: What's your processor architecture? Because I'm experiencing the same  on Apple M1 (arm64 as I understand).

Comment: Same problem here, any workaround?